# Fix an equation in place across overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am teaching optimization which means that I have often problem written on multiple lines (typically in an align environment). A common consists in moving / deleting / replacing some part of the problem. When I just want to make something appear / disappear \visible works pretty well. But if I have to move some part of the problem, using \only, the whole align move a little bit.

Is there a way to freeze a point (left hand side / middle column...) of the align to have it stay in place ?

MWE

```
\begin{equation*}
    \min_{x} \only<2>{\sup_{\lambda,\mu}} \quad f(x) 
    + \only<1>{\sup_{\lambda}} \lambda^\top (Ax - b) 
    + \sum_{i=1}^{n_I} \only<1>{\sup_{\mu_i \geq 0}} \mu_i h_i(x)
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Does the [`beamer` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 23.4 _Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise_ help you?

Comment: I guess using `\onslide` instead of `\only` is not an option ?

Comment: @BambOo I do not see what this would change, as far as I understand \onslide will act as \only or \visible depending on option.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks for the pointer, I might indeed use table with more columns. I would have to check if this solve the problem or not.

Comment: `\onslide` should keep the equation static but will leave blank space on some overlays